# Laravel Eloquent 'belongs to' relationship books and its category

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to print all books' name in 'books' table and its category associated. But it doesn't show any content nor error messages.

Model::Book.php

```
class Book extends Eloquent{
    protected $table ='books';

    public function bookCat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('BookCategory');
    }
}
```

Model::BookCategory.php

```
class BookCategory extends Eloquent{
    protected $table ='book_categories';

}
```

Controller::route.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $books = Book::all();

    return View::make('books')
    ->with('books', $books);
});
```

View::books.blade.php

```
@foreach ($books as $book)

<li>{{ $book->book_name }}</li>
- <small>{{ $book->bookCat }}</small>

@endforeach
```

Table::books

> (int)id, (string)book_name, (int)category_id

Table::book_categories

> (int)id, (string)category

Comment: Make sure the data in your database is correct and try printing the actual name: `{{ $book->bookCat->category }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the relationship to BookCategory.

```
class BookCategory extends Eloquent{
    protected $table ='book_categories';

    public function books() {
        return $this->hasMany('Book');
    }
}
```

Your local key doesn't match the model names, either, so you would need to specify that in the relation:

```
class Book extends Eloquent{
    protected $table ='books';

    public function bookCat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('BookCategory', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

You may also want to eager-load the categories in your controller, as your query is for the books:

```
$books = Book::with('bookCat')->get();
```

Comment: It says throw new \BadMethodCallException("Call to undefined method {$className}::{$method}()");

Comment: BadMethodCallException 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: The problem was the eager-loading method. When I change it to $books = Book::all(); it works. But how do I solve the eager-loading problem?

Comment: Oops, that's my bad - should have been `Book::with('bookCat')->get();`

Comment: Another thing, in your template you aren't actually echoing out the category name - change to `{{ $book->bookCat->category }}`

Comment: Not sure if <small> can be a sibling of <li> either, but maybe that's just me :)